# How do I round a number to n significant figures (not decimal places)?

Tags: mysql

I want to round to 2 significant figures, e.g. 1286 => 1300, 0.01286 => 0.013

I can solve the problem like this:

```
set @x = -0.0127;
select @x, ROUND(@x,2-floor(LOG10(abs(@x))))
```

But that's really ugly. For such a basic concept, surely there's a better way?

Comment: nope. mysql rounding functions have no concept of significant figures. that's something you have to supply.

Comment: Isn't 0.01286 to 2 significant figures just 0??

Comment: @Strawberry Yup: i'd even say `0.0` (which is saved as '0', nicely showing the issue of significancy and mysql)

Comment: Strawberry & Nanne - maybe you're thinking of rounding to decimal places? 0.01286 to 2 decimal places would be 0.01. (I corrected my example, where I'd mixed 2sf and 3sf)

Comment: @MichaelGrazebrook Nope. I'm thinking of basic mathematics (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

Comment: @Strawberry: Exactly. If you work out 0.01286 to 2sf using the Wikipedia article you reference, it's 0.013 not 0. Likewise 0.3 to 2sf would be 0.30. It's often used as a rough way to indicate how accurate your data is.

Comment: I don't think so. Rounding 0.01286 to 2 sf is 0.0 => 0. That's what the article says !?! Ah, apologies - I forgot that leading zeroes are 'insignificant'...